UpdateView in django
i can update email and others using the generic edit view "UpdateView" by giving the attribute name of my html inputs the corresponding field name so name="email" and so on. But the same thing doesn't work with field "user_permissions"
model = User
fields = [
    "email", 
    "is_superuser", 
    "is_active", 
    "is_staff", 
    "user_permissions",
    
]


 // options are added with a js event handler                          


user_permissions field is a many-to-many relationship. You have to handle that correctly. It is better to create a custom form that will support it:
user_permissions = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Permission.objects.all(),
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
)

Then use it in your view:
class UserUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = forms.YourCustomForm

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        if form_class is None:
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
        return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

Then in the front-end use basic "{{ form.as_p }}" to see how the html renders by default. This will help you to if then later, if you want you can use JS to populate the options.

okay i'm tryna do it.
